# Problem when importing module nested in the same root folder

Tags: python, import, init

I have my_super_root folder with such tree:

```
my_super_root:
   training_folder:
          my_subfolder:
              conftest.py
              submodule.py
```

and the code in conftest.py is just:

```
from training_folder.my_subfolder import submodule
```

when I run pytest from my_super_root level (it is set as a current working directory) I receive an error:

```
from training_folder.my_subfolder import my_submodule
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'training_folder'
```

However when I move conftest to the my_super_root and run pytest once again it works well. Why does it happen if folder in which you call pytest is added to sys.path?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python 3 Modules documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#:%7E:text=The%20__init__.py,on%20the%20module%20search%20path.):

"The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages. This prevents directories with a common name, such as `string`, unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path."

Comment: What do you mean by "common"? I think that "submodule" is not a common name. Even if I change this name to "my_super_submodule" this error still occurs.